# verify FCM registration token using python

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Firebase Cloud Messaging registration token from client. and i want to verify this registration token before I send push notification.

btw, I have tried https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens but I think this is for Auth tokens not for push notification.

how to verify registration token before send push notification ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot verify FCM registration token generated from device. Auth token created by firebase auth is JWT token which can be verified.

To verify if the token is generated from your client and project, you can send a test notification with your server key and check the response message, if token is altered obviously it will give you relevant error.